# Python - Need Help Getting User input stored in a list using python

Tags: python

I have this assignment where i have to create a list asking users to input 3 or 5 of their favorite movies, then im suppose to take that input and create a list with it and after display the list.

```
limit = 3

movieslist = []

while len(movieslist) < limit:  

    movie = raw_input("Enter The Name Of Your favorite Netflix movie" )
    print 
    movieslist.append(movie)

print "The Following Is A List Of Your Top 3 Favorite Netflix Movies:"

for x in movieslist:
    print x
```

Comment: You can do without the empty `print` by inserting `\n` (the newline character) at the beginning or end of the `raw_input` prompt string, e.g. `raw_input("Enter...Netflix\n")`

Answer (score 1):

Your professor's request is weird and I don't know if it'll satisfy her, but this'll work:

```
movieslist.extend([movie])
```

or equivalently:

```
movieslist += [movie]
```

This would also work but isn't using a while loop:

```
movieslist = [raw_input("....") for i in range(limit))]
```

Comment: Yeah that makes no sense. All these answers are essentially tricks to get around using `append`, while `append` is *the* most basic operation for building up a list. Being expected to make a list with a variable number of elements without being taught `append` is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [insert](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm) method

```
print "In the Following Program Enter Your Top 10 Favorite Netflix Movies When Prompted"

print ""

limit = 10

movieslist = []

while len(movieslist) < limit:  

    movie = raw_input("Enter The Name Of Your Top Movie(s) From Netflix" )
    print 
    movieslist.insert(0,movie)

print "The Following Is A List Of Your Top 10 Favorite Netflix Movies:"

for x in movieslist:
    print x
```

Comment: This actually has different semantics to `append` since it inserts at the beginning, so the movies will appear in reverse order. The equivalent would be `insert(len(movieslist) - 1, move)`. It looks weird, but so is disallowing `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a roundabout way if you want to troll/impress/confuse your professor:

```
def movie_generator():
    i = 0
    limit = 3
    while i < limit:
        i += 1
        yield raw_input("prompt")

movieslist = list(movie_generator())
```